# Tag synonym suggestion: [google-webmaster-tools] to [google-search-console]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Google renamed "Google Webmaster Tools" to "Google Search Console" [in May 2015](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2015/05/announcing-google-search-console-new), but tags for both names exist here.

- [google-webmaster-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-webmaster-tools) - 827 questions
- [google-search-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console) - 396 questions

Because "Google Search Console" is the official name, that should be the canonical tag.  The tag for "Google Webmaster Tools" should be merged into that.

Related: The Webmasters Stack Exchange created a synonym on their site [in May 2015](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/tag-google-webmaster-tools-to-google-search-console) and then made "Google Search Console" the canonical [in January 2017](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/time-to-change-the-google-webmaster-tools-tag).

Comment: I'm still wondering how a question using this tag will ever be on topic and not a customer support question.

Comment: Google Search Console has information about your website.  There are some programming questions for which the error message comes from Google Search Console.    Like [Tag:seo] questions, the majority of questions asked with these tags would be better asked on [webmasters.se] but a few are on-topic programming questions.

Comment: Few as in none? Both examples you concocted are off topic. Can you put an example where it's actually on topic and not just some vague "there might be some!"

Comment: [Warning: Unnecessary HSTS header over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022897/warning-unnecessary-hsts-header-over-http) is an example where the error message comes from Google Search Console but the question is about programming rewrite rules.  Also this question about programming JSON-LD: [How to specify product IDs in Google Search "application/ld+json" script without getting "Missing product ID (optional)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379561/how-to-specify-product-ids-in-google-search-application-ldjson-script-without)

Comment: The first is not a question about google search console, that's a **protocol violation** and one that any htst "validator" worth their salt would warn you about. Heck, the site that warns the user isn't even the search console! Also, off topic. What http request should have which header are a SEO question. Note, user agents would happily ignore the invalid header, as the spec says. The second one even has the SEO tag.

Comment: Again, not all SEO questions are off-topic here.   [Read the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info).

Comment: **All SEO questions that do not pertain to programming are off topic**, the same way that question do not pertain to programming are off topic. That apache question isn't programming, is software configuration and seo. The duplicate of that question is even closed as off topic https://stackoverflow.com/q/24144552/792066

Comment: The on/off topicness of SEO questions isn't relevant to whether or not this tag synonym should exist, given that there *are* valid programming questions under both tags.

Comment: @KevinB again, examples of valid questions that aren't off topic. Stephen has not been able to provide one. And if all questions under this tag are off topic the tag should not be synonymized, but just removed.

Comment: @Braiam [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69500371/google-oauth-credentials-for-different-scopes) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756153/webproperty-query-google-search-console-in-python) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553363/authorize-in-google-search-console) These really aren't hard to find

Comment: @KevinB [google webmaster api](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/) tag, same as before, same as before. Why are you giving more evidence to my argument? This tag shouldn't exist, and the correct tag already exist? [tag:google-api-webmasters]

Comment: We can debate the necessity of the tag elsewhere. The tags are now merged

Comment: @Machavity Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Merging [google-webmaster-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-webmaster-tools) into [google-search-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console) would reduce confusion and duplication.

Each of the tag wiki entries has some advantages over the other. Webmaster tools has a better wiki body, but search console has better usage guidance.  I suggest that the new tag wiki should combine the best of both worlds:

## Usage guidance

Use this tag for programming questions regarding the usage of Google Search Console tools and reports. Non-programming questions related to your website are better asked on https://webmaster.stackexchange.com

## Body

[Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about?hl=en), formerly "Google Webmaster Tools", provides you with detailed reports about your pages' visibility on Google. It provides the following functionalities:

**Get Google's view of your site and diagnose problems**

See how Google crawls and indexes your site and learn about specific problems we're having accessing it.

**Discover your link and query traffic**

View, classify, and download comprehensive data about internal and external links to your site with new link reporting tools. Find out which Google search queries drive traffic to your site, and see exactly how users arrive there.

**Share information about your site**

Tell us about your pages with Sitemaps: which ones are the most important to you and how often they change. You can also let us know how you would like the URLs we index to appear.

Comment: This would make the job of retagging more obnoxious, since instead of having two small groups of tags to review, we now have a big one. Placebo effect works, and making the task more daunting wouldn't help.

Answer (score -5):

The questions on comments are not about programming, and when they are, they aren't about the tool:

- [Getting a soft 404 error on redirect to login page in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922203/getting-a-soft-404-error-on-redirect-to-login-page-in-yii) users also see the 404 status code, but since the browser just show them the login page they don't care. The solution is on the php code.
- [Undefined offset 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728268/undefined-offset-1) Is not even about the API, but that OP doesn't write correct php code
- [Why google webmaster tools don't see the static version of my site but instead the template for the dynamic one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754712/how-does-the-spiderable-package-work-with-meteor) The answer says that is google's fault, and I ([and other Google customers](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/7986432/content-wider-than-screen-mobility-error-while-live-test-says-mobile-friendly?hl=en)) agree. Still a SEO question, since OP isn't interesting in knowing how Spiderable works, but bludgeon the Google tool into being good
- [UTF-8 encode URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096550/utf-8-encode-urls) about generating valid xml that describes a sitemap (remember site map is a file that describes the site, so every search engine benefit)

Just because they have the tag, doesn't mean they are about google search console. As I've demonstrated, those questions do not need the tag at all. I don't have the energy to check out the rest of the questions to write the argument on this question, but I've edited them when they are on topic, and voted to close the ones that aren't.

Both of these tags shouldn't exist. Instead of synonymization, a straight up clean up and burnination is in order. The clean up is required because there are questions with this tag that should be using others like [this google webmaster api question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68356002/792066) and [this php question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68902465/792066). A read of the newest 20, I found no question where this tag applies (the question is about the search console) that is also on topic. All of them are about using the web page without doing so programmatically (as is the API question before) or where the problem was somewhere else (like the PHP question).

[One of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67865798/792066) is very funny because I have periodically those issues on properties I manage and if you know where to look for (like [SEO oriented sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/117850/37527)) you will discover how inconsistent and poor those validations tools are with content.

Comment: Yet more examples of on-topic programming questions with these tags: [Getting a soft 404 error on redirect to login page in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922203/getting-a-soft-404-error-on-redirect-to-login-page-in-yii) and [Undefined offset 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728268/undefined-offset-1) and [How does the Spiderable package work with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754712/how-does-the-spiderable-package-work-with-meteor) and [UTF-8 encode URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096550/utf-8-encode-urls)

Comment: [100vh in Google Search Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995838/100vh-in-google-search-console) and [Using Angular to dynamically add and remove \<meta name="robots" content="noindex" /\>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420970/using-angular-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-meta-name-robots-content-noindex)

Comment: I agree that the vast majority of questions that use these tags are off-topic and some on-topic questions could use other tags.   However, not ALL the questions are off-topic, nor would these tags meet the [other three criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).  Plus with 1,200 questions that would need to be evaluated and edited, the process would slow and require enormous effort.

Comment: In any case, burnination is at best tangential.  It would be just as easy to burninate once the tags were merged as it would be beforehand.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller 1: users also see the 404 status code, but since the browser just show them the login page they don't care. The solution is on the php code. 2: Is not even about the API, but that OP doesn't write correct php code. 3: The answer says that is google's fault, and I agree. Still a SEO question, since OP isn't interesting in knowing how Spiderable works, but bludgeon the Google tool into being good. 4: about generating valid xml that describes a sitemap (remember site map is a file that describes the site, so every search engine benefit). Are you reading the questions at all?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No, if we are going to touch the tags, we should touch once and make them ready. Lets focus on the permanent solution, instead of revising these tags twice.

Comment: The creation of a tag synonym is a single action performed by a moderator.  With a single click, every question with the old tag is converted to the canonical tag.   The tags don't have to get touched twice.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Don't you see that this discussion is going to be had _twice_?

Comment: [Your tag edits to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6096550/revisions) don't make sense and cause harm.  That question is about both character encodings and google search console.  Editing them out of the tags just to try and make a point here is wrong.